# how can we bind an event to the element with no identifier(class or ID)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was just exploring the code of a web application and saw this `select` element which doesnt have any identifier(`class` or `id`) but there are two events that are attached to this element

[image]

I was just wondering how these events are attached to this element. I mean I know some of the ways through which the events can be attached but I wont be able to attach an event to thie element.
Attaching the event to the first child of the element with `class="version_switcher_placeholder"` will not be good idea I think.

Edit: Everyone here is saying that we can get the element with `class` name `version_switcher_placeholder`, I understand this and its alredy mentioned in question itself.

I this the inly way that event can be attached to the concerned select element.

Comment: The select is nested in a span, the span has a class name, with a bit of css magick the person can pinpoint to that select for example ".version_switcher_placeholder select"

Answer (score 2):

First of all it not a good idea to keep your elements without any selector if you want to do dom manipulation. But if you can not change this, and if you are sure to do this, you can use the combination of [Child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) along with [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) psuedo code.

Consider this example for a reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Title
    </title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li>
        <select>
            <option value="testVal1">testVal1</option>
            <option value="testVal2">testVal2</option>
            <option value="testVal3">testVal3</option>
            <option value="testVal4">testVal4</option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var selectElement = document.querySelector("body > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(1) > select:nth-child(1)");
    selectElement.style.color = 'red';

    selectElement.addEventListener("change", function(event){
        console.log( event );
    })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like

```
$('.version_switcher_placeholder > select').on('change', function() { // do });
```

To bind events to it using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly this could be done with `getElementsByTagName` like so:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].onchange = function(){...};
```

Just have to specify the correct `[index]`

Comment: Yes, this only works if you can determine the index. If theres 2 select elements then either [0] or [1], etc.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple ways,

```
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.version_switcher_placeholder > select').on('change', function() { 
     //code here   
     });
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select elements by tag name.
[getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) and attach events.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

function printTag() {
    console.log(this);
}

for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener("click", printTag, false);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Tab 1</li>
    <li>Tab 2</li>
    <li>Tab 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```